# How to display a tiled background for all resolutions?

Tags: android, user-interface, themes, android-activity

I have a texture.png which I would like to tile, to create a textured background for my window.

Will I run into any problems with different screen resolutions?

If so, what is the best way to support a textured background for multiple devices?

Should I have 1 image instead? How large should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create 3 different versions of your texture and place them in the ldpi, mdpi and hdpi folders appropriately. You can find more on the different densities [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). In order to create a background drawable, create an XML file like it is described here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/window-bg-speed.html

The attribute `android:tileMode="repeat"` will do the magic stuff for you. :-)